# ASP Chart, Year, Month, Day drill down

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, drilldown

I'm trying to make a drill down chart(stack column) in ASP.NET(C#) which presents a total revenue by year(2011, 2012, 2013 etc.), when I click a column let say the year 2012, the chart shows the total revenue from each month from that year. This the same for month to day.

So this is the idea, but I have no clue how to make something like this, I've searched days finding some drill down examples but nothing worked for me, there are some examples but not with date drill down.

This is what I got already, but how further?

Database Table definition:
RevenueNumbers: int
Date: Date

(Create and fill chart from SQL server)

```
public SqlConnection conn;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString);

        string query = "SELECT SUM(RevenueNumber) AS TotalRevenue, DATENAME(YYYY, Date) AS Year FROM test GROUP BY DATENAME(YYYY, Date)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();

        Chart1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Series Series1 = new Series();
        Series1.XValueMember = "Year";
        Series1.YValueMembers = "TotalRevenue";

        Chart1.Series.Add(Series1);
        Chart1.Series[0].PostBackValue = "#XVAL";
        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        Chart1.DataBind();

    }
```

(HTML)

```
<div>  
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
        <chartareas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </chartareas>
    </asp:Chart>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you having troubles with? Registering user clicks? SQL query? ...

Comment: Hi Walther, 

I have no idea how to code a "click"event to drill down a total revenue from Year>Month>Day on a ASP.NET chart, that's my trouble.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the official documentation? Maybe this could help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.click(v=vs.100).ASPX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the Points collection on your Series and set the Url:

```
foreach (DataPoint p in Chart1.Series[0].Points)
{
    p.Url = string.Format("details.aspx?id={0}", p.XValue);
}
```

That should get you squared away.

Answer (score 1):

Made some code, it's working but a bit messy

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString);
        string query = "";
        string Year = "";
        string Month = "";
        if (Request["Year"] != null) Year = Request["Year"].ToString();
        if (Request["Month"] != null) Month = Request["Month"].ToString();
        if ((Year == "") && (Month == ""))
        {
            query = "SELECT SUM(TotalRevenue) AS Total, YEAR(Date) AS Year FROM test GROUP BY YEAR(Date)";
        }
        else if (Month == "")
        {
            query = "SELECT SUM(TotalRevenue) AS Total, MONTH(Date) AS year FROM test WHERE YEAR(Date) = " + Year + "  GROUP BY MONTH(Date)";
        }
        else
        {
            query = "SELECT SUM(TotalRevenue) AS Total, DAY(Date) AS Year FROM test WHERE YEAR(Date) = " + Year + " AND MONTH(Date) = " + Month + "  GROUP BY DAY(Date)";
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();

        Chart1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Series Series1 = new Series();
        Series1.XValueMember = "Year";
        Series1.YValueMembers = "Total";

        Chart1.Series.Add(Series1);

        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        Chart1.DataBind();

        foreach (DataPoint p in Chart1.Series[0].Points)
        {
            if ((Year != "") && (Month != ""))
            {
                p.Url = string.Format("Default.aspx");
            }
            else if (Year != "")
            {
                p.Url = string.Format("Default.aspx?Year={0}&Month={1}", Year, p.XValue);
            }
            else
            {
                p.Url = string.Format("Default.aspx?Year={0}", p.XValue);
            }
        }

    }
```